# Difference between Capacitor and a battery

Tags: electromagnetism, capacitance, voltage, batteries, electrochemistry

Capacitor stores electric charge and battery also stores electric charge. SO whats the difference between them?

Comment: Have you done any research? What battery type? Lead acid, li ion?

Comment: any type of battery

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between a battery and a charged capacitor?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/32391/)

Comment: In general caps are very small and store tiny charges to function in circuits, they respond quickly to current needs (in the pico, nano, and micro, milli seconds).  Batteries are used for energy and tend to be much larger and use a much stronger chemistry( ex: ions in solution), they work slowly but steadily.  Some caps can hold a lot of charge, as much as a very small battery (electrolytic, use a moderate chemistry) and last 10 plus years.  Most batteries last ~  5 years, the ceramic tiny caps use no chemistry (ion flow)  and last many many years.

Comment: On a computer motherboard there are many small ceramic caps next to each chip to smooth the current, there is a small battery for the clock chip, and huge electrolytic caps in the power supply to smooth the AC and provide extra power for example when the HDD starts to spin or when you start to play games and the graphics card starts using a lot of current.